Converting hierarchically structured plain text into R data frame
I am trying to take a document with a hierarchical structure (header, subheader, point, subpoint) which has nested relations between elements and convert the text into a R data frame where each related element has a corresponding variable (header, subheader, point, subpoint). In my case, the points and subpoints are main questions and subquestions as the document is an interview guide. It that is unclear, here is a visual:
I. Section One. A. Subsection One-One. 1. Question One. a. Subquestion One-One. b. Subquestion One-Two. II. Section Two. A. Subsection Two-One. 2. Question Two. a. Subquestion Two-One...
In the R code below, I am trying to take the input text and convert this to the format shown in the desired_df tibble.
My intuition was to split the text at each given element using str_split() to split by header/subheader/question/subquestion and map() to iterate over each nested element, extract the text with regular expressions, and send each element off to a data frame. I am not so sure how to do this last part about sending off the elements to make the data frame. This last part of the code is poorly documented as I'm not quite sure how to do this yet.
The following is a reprex of the R code I have been working on. I am open to different approaches and am trying out the tidyr::separate_<longer/wider>_regex() functions as an alternative.
library(tidyverse)

# This is an example of an interview guide. There are main sections, 
  # subsections within each section, questions within each subsection, 
  # and subquestions within each question. 
text <- "I. Section One A. Subsection One-One 1. [If not asked before] Question 1? a. subquestion one-one? b. subquestion one-two? B. Subsection One-Two. 2. [Misc. Text] Question 2? a. subquestion two-one? b. subquestion two-two? II. Section Two 3. Question 3? 4. Question 4? a. subquestion four-one? 5. Question 5? X. Final Section 6. [Skip if answered already] Question 6?"



# I am trying to translate this text into a data frame which encodes the 
  # hierarchical structure of the interview guide. The following is what I am
  # trying to produce. 

# This data frame captures the hierarchical structure of an interview guide with
  # headers, subheaders, questions, and subquestions all nested inside each other 
  # by simply having these related elements in a single row
desired_df <- 
  tibble(
    section = c("I. Section One", # first main section (with 2 questions)
                "I. Section One", 
                "II. Section Two", # second main section (with 3 questions)
                "II. Section Two", 
                "II. Section Two",
                "X. Final Section"), # third main section (with 1 question)
    
    subsection = c("A. Subsection One-One", # Only first section has subsections
                   "B. Subsection One-Two",   
                   NA_character_, 
                   NA_character_, 
                   NA_character_, 
                   NA_character_), 
    
    question = c("1. [If not asked before] Question 1?", # main questions within each (sub)section
                 "2. [Misc. Text] Question 2?", 
                 "3. Question 3?", 
                 "4. Question 4?", 
                 "5. Question 5?", 
                 "6. [Skip if answered already] Question 6?"), 
    
    
    subquestion = c("a. subquestion one-one? b. subquestion one-two?",  # if applicable, these are subquestions following corresponding main question
                    "a. subquestion two-one? b. subquestion two-two?", 
                    NA_character_, 
                    "a. subquestion four-one?", 
                    NA_character_, 
                    NA_character_)
  )



# My idea to produce the data frame is to split the text into each nested structure (by main sections, then subsections within sections, then questions within subsections, then not splitting but separating main questions from subquestions (there may be multiple subquestions but I'm just lumping these together)). 

# I am thinking maybe it might be easier to use the new `separate()` functions (`separate_<wider/longer>_regex()`) with the same regex, but not the nested lists? 

# splitting guide into main header sections (below, I will extract header titles)
sections <- str_split(
  text, 
  # splitting between punctuation followed by space and uppercase roman numerals
  "(?<=[:punct:])\\s(?=[IVX]+)"
)

# now this is the main mapping section where each section is split and
  # relevant text is extracted. 

# first iterating through each section in the guide
nested_structure <- map(sections, \(.section) { 
  
  # identify the main section header text
  # first is uppercase roman numeral followed by period, space, and some text. 
    # Then lookahead to either subsection (uppercase letter), main question (digit), 
    # or bracket opening (present sometimes for misc. notes). 
  section_name <- str_extract(.section, 
                              "^([IVX]+)\\.\\s(.*?)(?=[A-Z]\\.|\\d{1,3}\\.|\\[)")
  
  # now that the section title text is identified, it should be 
    # removed the other elements can be identified
    # this is what will be using below to split text into hierarchical structure
  # same regex is used as above, now to remove
  rem_sections <- str_remove(.section, 
                            "^([IVX]+)\\.\\s(.*?)(?=[A-Z]\\.|\\d{1,3}\\.|\\[)")
  
  # with the main section titles identified and removed, the text can be split 
    # into subsections within main sections
    # Now below, I will iterate across these subsections
  # same idea as initial section split, but not splitting between punctuation,
    # space, and start of new subsection indicated by capital letter
  subsections <- str_split(rem_sections, 
                           "(?<=[:punct:])\\s(?=[A-Z]\\.)")
  
  # now iterating over subsections 
  map(subsections, \(.subsection) {
    
    # identifying title text of subsections
    # subsection title text contained between capital letter, 
      # period, space, some text, and then a question (end of subsection title)
    subsection_name <- str_extract(.subsection[[1]], 
                                   "^[A-Z]\\.(.*?)(?=\\d{1,3}\\.)")
    
    # now removing subsection titles so not present in questions
    # same regex, to remove
    rem_subsections <- str_remove(.subsection[[1]], 
                                  "^[A-Z]\\.(.*?)(?=\\d{1,3}\\.)")
    
    # splitting text into questions present in subsections 
    # again, splitting, but now by question, so between punctuation and 
      # new question indicated by digit
    questions <- str_split(rem_subsections,
                           "(?<=[:punct:])\\s(?=\\d{1,3}\\.)")
    
    # to access question text, I have to step down into the nested list structure
      # produced by splitting subsections into questions (from the section level
      # to subsection to question, so three nested loops)
    # this part seems a bit wonky and I think there is probably a better way if
      # I do the splitting above differently
    map(questions, \(.section) {
      map(.section, \(.subsection) {
        map(.subsection, \(.question) {
          
          # identifying main question text
          # contained between digit, space, question text, 
            # and then either a subquestion (always starting with "a."
            # or the end of the string, meaning no more questions)
          main_question_text <- str_extract(.question, 
                                            "^\\d{1,3}\\.(.*?)(?=a\\.|$)")
          
          # now identifying the subquestion text for each main question
          # this regex is maybe not very good because there could be 
            # matches which aren't the start of a subquestion... 
          subquestion_text <- str_extract(.question, 
                                          "a\\.\\s(.*?)$")
          
          # This is the part now that I am trying to export the 
            # elements I have extracted (section_name, subsection_name, 
            # main_question_text, subquestion_text). 
          # The important thing is that the hierarchical relation is preserved, 
            # but I am not so sure how to do this throughout the many 
            # map() calls. 
          
          
          list(main_question = main_question_text, 
               subquestion = subquestion_text)
          
        })
      })
    }) |>
      
      list(subsection = subsection_name,
           # I was trying out this placeholder for prior list, 
            # but I am probably not doing it right!
           question = _)  
  }) |> 
    
    list(section = section_name, 
         subsection = _)
  
})



# this definitely does not work, and not all questions are captured in the code above for some reason. 
# df <- 
#   map_df(nested_structure, \(.section) {
#     map_df(.section$subsection, \(.subsection) {
#       map_df(.subsection$question, \(.question) {
#         
#         tibble(
#           section = .section$section, 
#           subsection = .subsection$subsection, 
#           question = .question$main_question, 
#           subquestion = .question$subquestion
#         )
#         
#       })
#     })
#   })

Created on 2024-12-04 with reprex v2.1.1

This is a partial solution that is pretty far along, but I need to go to sleep. It's quite late in my time zone :). Section II remains to be fixed, but I've simplified much of the process by using str_split_1 instead of str_split. It returns a flattened character vector that I find mentally easier to work with. To reduce space, I've removed your comments, but they were extremely helpful, especially the regex explanations.
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
text <- "I. Section One A. Subsection One-One 1. [If not asked before] Question 1? a. subquestion one-one? b. subquestion one-two? B. Subsection One-Two. 2. [Misc. Text] Question 2? a. subquestion two-one? b. subquestion two-two? II. Section Two 3. Question 3? 4. Question 4? a. subquestion four-one? 5. Question 5? X. Final Section 6. [Skip if answered already] Question 6?"
sections <- str_split_1(
  text, 
  "(?<=[:punct:])\\s(?=[IVX]+)"
)
    nested_structure <- map(sections, \(.section) { 
  
  section_name <- str_extract(.section, 
                              "^([IVX]+)\\.\\s(.*?)(?=[A-Z]\\.|\\d{1,3}\\.|\\[)")
  
  rem_sections <- str_remove(.section, 
                             "^([IVX]+)\\.\\s(.*?)(?=[A-Z]\\.|\\d{1,3}\\.|\\[)")
  
  subsections <- str_split_1(rem_sections, 
                             "(?<=[:punct:])\\s(?=[A-Z]\\.)")
  
  map(subsections, \(.subsection) {
    
    subsection_name <- str_extract(.subsection, 
                                   "^[A-Z]\\.(.*?)(?=\\d{1,3}\\.)")
    
    rem_subsections <- str_remove(.subsection, 
                                  "^[A-Z]\\.(.*?)(?=\\d{1,3}\\.)")
    question <- str_extract(rem_subsections, "^\\d{1,3}\\.(.*?)(?=a\\.|$)")
    subq <- str_remove(rem_subsections, "^\\d{1,3}\\.(.*?)(?=a\\.|$)")
    # subq_v <- str_split_1(subq, "(?<=\\?)\\s(?=[a-z]\\.)") # if you want subquestions split as well
    
    tibble(section = section_name, 
           subsection = subsection_name,
           question = question,
           subq = subq
           )
  })
}) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()
> dput(nested_structure)
structure(list(section = c("I. Section One ", "I. Section One ", 
"II. Section Two ", "X. Final Section "), subsection = c("A. Subsection One-One ", 
"B. Subsection One-Two. ", NA, NA), question = c("1. [If not asked before] Question 1? ", 
"2. [Misc. Text] Question 2? ", "3. Question 3? 4. Question 4? ", 
"6. [Skip if answered already] Question 6?"), subq = c("a. subquestion one-one? b. subquestion one-two?", 
"a. subquestion two-one? b. subquestion two-two?", "a. subquestion four-one? 5. Question 5?", 
"")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
> nested_structure
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  section             subsection                question                            subq 
  <chr>               <chr>                     <chr>                               <chr>
1 "I. Section One "   "A. Subsection One-One "  "1. [If not asked before] Question… "a. …
2 "I. Section One "   "B. Subsection One-Two. " "2. [Misc. Text] Question 2? "      "a. …
3 "II. Section Two "   NA                       "3. Question 3? 4. Question 4? "    "a. …
4 "X. Final Section "  NA                       "6. [Skip if answered already] Que… ""   

